# Transform XML Action in LogicApps standard

Tags: xslt, azure-logic-app-standard

I have a scenario to transform XML to JSON using XSLT Transformation in LogicApps standard.

I have written an XSLT transformation, it is working as expected in "Transform XML" action in LogicApps consumption  but giving attached error in "Transform XML" action in LogicApps Standard.

Your help is appreciated.

[image]

Tried adding below setting in App Setting but still no help.

AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags = EnableMultiLanguageWorker

Comment: Have you added the assemblies?

Comment: There no assemblies in my case. Only one simple xslt to transform.

Comment: Can you share your input data in text format

Comment: Find the sample Input XML is below. In XSLT we are grouping based on Category. and one extra field is being added in output file with current date time.                                    <root><item><orderedcompany>XYZCompany</orderedcompany><category>A</category><value>10</value><inventory>500</inventory></item><item><orderedcompany>Infosys</orderedcompany><category>B</category><value>20</value><inventory>100</inventory></item><item><orderedcompany>Infosys</orderedcompany><category>A</category><value>30</value><inventory>1000</inventory></item></root>

Comment: Can you also share your `Map` file?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="categoryKey" match="item" use="category" />
  <xsl:template match="/root">
   <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>"Orderdetails": {</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>"CompanyName": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="item/orderedcompany" />
   <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>"orderdate":"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
   <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>

Comment: <xsl:text>"ItemDetails": [</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('categoryKey', category)[1])]"/>
   <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
   <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>"category": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="category" />
   <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>"inventorydetails":</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="key('categoryKey', category)">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>"value":"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="value" />
    <xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>"inventoryprice":"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="inventory"/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text><xsl:if test="position() != last()">
     <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>}</xsl:text><xsl:if test="position() != last()">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
    
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Was unable to put in single message, splitted into 3 comments..